# Font-Face not working

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to learn to use `font-face` to add a different font to my browser but I seem to be missing something in the code because the style is not applying. Here is my code:

```
<div id="logo">
      <img src="img/header/THANATHOS.png" alt="Logo"/>
      <p>a gamers community</p>
</div>

<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HarlowSolid';
    src: url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

div#logo p{
    font-family: HarlowSolid , Helvetica , sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is the include path correct? remember it's relative to CSS file, not the HTML one

Comment: did you forget to wrap the css code inside <style type="text/css"> and </style> tags?

Comment: What's not working? In which browsers? Can you reach the fonts by URL? Have you peeked in a dev toolbar yet? Does it work with other fonts? And absolute paths? It helps if you're more specific about the problem, and the things you've tried to debug.

Comment: I'd recommend not using capital letters in directory and file names. Better practioce to always use lower case when possible. Check your paths anyway. You don't actually have that style tag in the BODY of your page do you. That wouldn't be cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you've either wrapped it in `<style> /* Code Here  */</style>` tags, or put it in your style sheet.

Also check that the path to the file you've written that code in.
So if it's in `/css/style.css` and harlowSolid.woff is in root folder called `fonts`, then your code would need to be `url('../Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.woff')`

Also check that the browser you're testing has [support for font-face](http://caniuse.com/fontface). Though with the conditionals you've included it should be unlikely to face a problem.

Just to confirm: The actual code you've posted is correct, so check your file exists/structured properly.

If you're using Chrome/Safari/FF, you can usually right click -> Inspect Element, look out for the red cog symbol in the bottom right corner which will denote coding/resource errors. (Click it to see the description of the problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Are the second src right?
Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HarlowSolid';
    src: url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    **src:** url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('Fonts/normal/HarlowSolid.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```